# File encoding in WebStorm

Tags: encoding, utf-8, webstorm

One of the files in my project contains German Umlaut characters, But these do not display when I bring the file up in WebStorm. Instead, I get black diamonds with a question mark in the middle which would seem to indicate that the character in question is not understood.

I found another thread here on stackoverflow.com which explained how to set file encodings inside WebStorm both for the current project and as the default for all projects. That's pretty easy to do. You just go to File --> Settings --> File Encodings for the one and File --> Default Settings --> File Encodings for the other.

When I go to those pages in my WebStorm app, I see settings for 'IDE Encoding' and 'Project Encoding'. Both are set for UTF-8. Yet these characters are not showing up when I view the file inside WebStorm and are clearly not being understood as such in the program itself, either. (I'm using them inside regular expressions which fail because the umlauted characters are not understood.)

When I open the same file inside Ultra Edit, another text editing program I use outside of WebStorm, the characters display as they should, indicating that the accented characters really are there in the file.

Any idea why WebStorm is not recognizing these characters?

Comment: Did you check the actual encoding of your file?

Comment: 1) What kind of file is that (html/js/etc)? 2) What encoding WebStorm is using for that file? (you can see it in status bar when that file is opened in Editor) 3) If IDE still picks wrong encoding, you can override it in that settings screen -- just find your file in a tree there and manually assign  specific encoding 4) Any chance of sharing such file (actual file, not just copy-pasted content)?

Comment: Hi. It's a .js file. I have a Meteor method stored in a .js file called convertToLate.js which is in my Server file along with some others.  
  
Down at the bottom of the page in the status bar, the file is marked as UTF8. I checked the other open files, as welll, and they all show up as UTF8 except that for one of the HTML files it still reads UTF-8 but is grayed out.  
  
I went to change manually and got a message saying I could either reload or convert. I tried both. Neither worked. I get an odd message saying it will change the content of the file. It seems to think my UTF-8 is not valid.

Comment: So .. can you share such file somewhere? It would be good to download it as is (unchanged) and see what another tool/editor thinks about it. 2)  HTML -- you cannot change encoding of some files if they have standard `charset` attribute (standard stuff in `<head>` section). 3) You need to use "Reload" and not "Convert" -- first just reads file using different encoding while second actually changes encoding of certain (affected) characters and can damage your file if done incorrectly (e.g. original encoding was wrong etc). P.S. Please use `@username` if you want that person to be notified

Comment: Thanks, @LazyOne, for your assistance. Based on your info, I decided to try to open the file in Notepad and re-save it as UTF-8. That made it so the German characters display correctly inside WebStorm now. So I have to guess UltraEdit (whose iffy Unicode functionality has tripped me up before) just doesn't save files in a way that's compatible with WebStorm. --- However, now Meteor doesn't seem to be able to read the file. So I guess I'm not quite yet done solving this problem. If you have any ideas, please let me know. And thanks very much for your assistance in resolving the other issue.

Comment: (What I mean is that Meteor is now throwing a whole series of errors saying it can't process the info I am retrieving from the method call to the method stored in this file. It was processing it just fine before aside from not processing the non-ASCII characters properly.) @LazyOne

Comment: I'm not working with Meteor and have no real idea of what error might be or what may cause it. Maybe you have saved the file with BOM header and Meteor does not like it?

Comment: I wish I knew how to check for a BOM header. My understanding is that WebStorm doesn't want a BOM header (I read that somewhere), but I have no idea about Meteor. And I don't even know how I'd check if it was there or not. I can't believe how such a little thing can be so complicated. Really frustrating.

Comment: --moving this comment to 'answer' box--

Answer (score 0):

OK, I believe I have figured this out. If I save the UTF-8 file *with* a BOM, WebStorm can display the Unicode characters contained in the file, but Meteor *cannot* run the file. ---

However, if I save the UTF-8 file *without* a BOM, WebStorm cannot display the Unicode characters contained in the file but Meteor *can* run the file. However, Meteor ignores the non-ASCII characters because it apparently can't decipher them.   --

So I have to conclude that WS and Meteor are not compatible with each other in terms of how they handle non-ASCII text. But maybe there's a way around it?

Comment: 1) https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6489 2) IDE can work just fine with UTF-8 encoded file without BOM -- I'm working with such files on daily basis (hell, all .php files must follow this rule otherwise PHP interpreter will just echo BOM into output breaking the logic). It has to be your settings-specific issue.

Comment: Thanks, @LazyOne. 

I didn't notice the github link when I saw your message before. I followed it and it appears you are saying that I may need to download the latest fixes for Meteor 1.3 to fix this problem.   ---  
  
On the other hand, in the latter part of the message, you're saying it should be working anyway and that you think it may be a settings-specific issue.  ---  
  
I had decided I'd just move to \uNNNN style codes, but maybe I can get it working in another way. I guess I'll start by trying to install the Meteor update. Thanks.

Comment: -- moving this comment to an Answer box --

Comment: Please share such file (non-modified file that can be downloaded as is) so that I can check it locally -- maybe you using some wrong encoding or something. Also share some screenshot of the same place in file in both WebStorm & Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I did two things:

1- I upgraded to the stable version of Meteor 1.3 (which was just released within the past few hours it appears)
2- I had to manually edit my UTF8 .js file directly within WebStorm since it would no longer display the proper characters in either Notepad or UltraEdit. ---

That worked. I now have the Unicode characters displaying in WebStorm and running correctly in Meteor.

I'm not sure I understand why it is now working, but I'm glad it is. Thanks to @LazyOne for helping me to know where to even start with fixing this. –

Comment: Thanks for the offer, @LazyOne. I've got a whole pile of other Meteor issues I need to work out, so I'll pass on this one for the moment. (It's enough for me that it is working, and I assume something in my upgrade to 1.3 is responsible for it working now.)